# td-agent error [Cannot output messages with tag] for loggly

Tags: fluentd

Getting below error on td-agent configured on creating a store for loggly. required info as below

```
ubuntu 14.04. fluent-plugin-forest (0.3.3) fluent-plugin-loggly (0.0.8)
```

2016-10-10 10:18:58 +0000 [error]: failed to configure/start sub output loggly: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)
2016-10-10 10:18:58 +0000 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.0.0/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:505:in `initialize'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-loggly-0.0.8/lib/fluent/plugin/out_loggly.rb:37:in`new'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-loggly-0.0.8/lib/fluent/plugin/out_loggly.rb:37:in `start'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-forest-0.3.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forest.rb:133:in`block in plant'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-forest-0.3.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forest.rb:128:in `synchronize'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-forest-0.3.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forest.rb:128:in`plant'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluent-plugin-forest-0.3.1/lib/fluent/plugin/out_forest.rb:168:in `emit'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/output.rb:32:in`next'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/buffer.rb:193:in `block in emit'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in`mon_synchronize'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/buffer.rb:187:in `emit'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/output.rb:448:in`emit'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/output.rb:32:in `next'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/out_copy.rb:74:in`emit'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/event_router.rb:88:in `emit_stream'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:248:in`receive_lines'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:343:in `call'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:343:in`wrap_receive_lines'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:536:in `call'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:536:in`on_notify'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:369:in `on_notify'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:470:in`call'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:470:in `on_change'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cool.io-1.4.4/lib/cool.io/loop.rb:88:in`run_once'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/cool.io-1.4.4/lib/cool.io/loop.rb:88:in `run'
/opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/fluentd-0.12.20/lib/fluent/plugin/in_tail.rb:233:in`run'
2016-10-10 10:18:58 +0000 [error]: Cannot output messages with tag '*****-nginx-ip-*-*-*-*

Answer (score 1):

We have found net-http-persistent 3.0.0 not compatible with fluent-plugin-forest. because of that td-agent not able to sent log to loggly using fluent-plugin-forest.

solution remove net-http-persistent(3.0.0)

`td-agent-gem uninstall net-http-persistent --force`

`td-agent-gem install net-http-persistent -v 2.9.4`

error
 [error]: /opt/td-agent/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/net-http-persistent-3.0.0/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:505:in `initialize'